# Open-source, multi-user self-hostable task management with spreadsheet views?

Tags: open-source, self-hosted, spreadsheet, task-management, multi-user

There are many open-source for task management software these days, as noted in e.g.:

- https://opensource.com/article/18/2/agile-project-management-tools (2020)
- https://medium.com/issuehunt/5-open-source-project-management-tools-c33a19132ed6 (2018)

However, I cannot if any of those tools support the following:

- Ability to self-host (install on own (Linux) server)
- Multi-user (ability for multiple users to log in)
- Gantt-chart would be nice

... *and* - one thing important for my use case - is that the software supports different spreadsheet views: as one example - Have a user/participant name as column header, and each respective task assigned to that user, shows up in a row under that column:

[image: spread01.png]

... then have also the same information represented, so each task is one row under Tasks column, followed by assigned users/participants column:

[image: spread02.png]

It would be great if also all tasks - in any view - also show their associated attributes, like due date, severity, etc. Even better if, for example in the second view, you could sort tasks by date, severity etc.

Is there anything like this out there?

Answer (score 1):

One could create the functionalities you describe with a base of taskwarrior.

- You can an host taskwarrior yourself on both windows and Linux
- It allows multiple users on multiple devices, including android
- You could use this taskwarrior hook to automatically generate Gantt charts from the tasks: https://github.com/8ware/task-gantt
- However it would be a bit more fancy if you would write a bit of code that generates the plantUML Gantt charts based on the tasks in the `pending.data`.
- As a spreadsheet overview you could use this hook: http://wpitchoune.net/ptask/ but I think that is not quite what you had in mind.
- A real spreadsheet interface could be built with a Collabora Online sheet that can be hosted on an https website that you can host yourself with your own dns server, on a docker using nextcloud and lets-encrypt. Besides being slightly tedious to set this up, you would also have to parse the `pending.data` and other `.data` files from json format to a sheets overview.

This is a bit like maslows hammer though, so I can imagine there are easier implementations available.